# How do I call the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering why my code is not calling/running the function:

```
    TA = input('Would you like to throw again? (Y for yes and N for no) ')
if TA == ('Y') or ('y') is True:
    classMain()    
else:
    print('Goodybye!')
```

This is what I'm using to call the function, and this is the function itself:

```
DI = input('\nHow many sides are on your dice? ')

def classMain():
    global DI
    DI
    while DI.isdigit() is False:
        DI = input('\nPlease enter a real number: ')
        continue
        break
```

So how can i Call the function (Function is before the first bit)?

The difference between the one you marked as a duplicate and mine, is that the function is not running which in this case is classMain().

Comment: The duplicate question shows how to achieve what you need, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/1258041) explains the kind of error you have in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your trouble is in your expectation of how `if TA == ('Y') or ('y') is True:` behaves.  It does not check if `TA` is either of `Y` or `y`.  Instead, it checks if `TA == 'Y'`, then checks if `'y' is True`, which will *never* be true.

If you want to test multiple valid conditions for a variable use `in` like so:

```
if TA in ('y', 'Y'):
```

Of preferably, use `.lower()`:

```
if TA.lower() == 'y':
```

Comment: Thanks that makes complete sense :) , but the function is still not running so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @PrinceDinar Based on your questions so far, I'd suggest you run through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)